# Processing one row of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible to load one row only of a csv file on python?
I have a huge csv file and I just want to copy its headers. Can I do this in a memory efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `next`:

```
with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `next()` on the reader object.

```
headerrow = next(reader)
```